# Excel- IF 2 values on the same line THEN

Tags: excel

Long time browser, first time "asker"

In an Excel sheet, with several lines with values.
First cell of each line is a date, and the rest are number values.
column A is the date. Columns B thru V are number values. 
on each line on Column W i'm looking for a way to show the date from column A, IF and only IF, there are 2 instances= "1" on the that line.
Kind of like a VLOOKUP, but only IF there are 2 instances of "1" on that line.

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: =IF(COUNTIF(A2:V2,1)=2,A1,"")

Answer (score 0):

Use the `CountIf(` function in combination with an `If(` statement.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:V1,1)=2,A1,"")
```

This will count the number of times the cells A1 to V1 contain the value `1`, and the `=2` will determine if that count is 2 instances or not. Then it will either return the relevant cell from column A or blank.

Comment: If you drag this down, then the result will always be A1, perhaps B1 or C1 may also be relevant on dragging...

Comment: @SolarMike It appears I didn't read the question correctly, I thought the date from A1 was always needed, rather than the date from column A. I amended my answer.